# Is there an idiom that means "look familiar"?

Tags: idiom-request

Is there an idiom that means "look familiar"? I am pretty sure there's a handful of expression that means "look familiar" or something similar? Do you know any such expression?

For example:

> Does this piece of painting ____ the police chief asked?

Comment: What's wrong with just *looks familiar*? Why are you looking for something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Note that *piece of painting* isn't normally idiomatic in English.)

---

A very common idiomatic usage in this context is:

> *The police chief asked "Does this painting **ring a bell**?"*

---

> **ring a bell** (also **ring any bells**)
>    *to sound familiar*

Don't take that ***sound*** too literally though. The expression can just as well be used in contexts where it might be directly replaceable by *...**seem, look, smell, taste, feel** familiar*.

In much the same vein there's also ***touch / strike a chord***, which *could* (just about) be used in OP's context. But that one often has stronger allusions to ***strike / hit home*** which usually conveys *particularly*, often *painfully* relevant. As in *His story about being mugged struck a chord with me* (because I myself had been mugged, so listening to him brought back disturbing memories).

Answer (score 1):

You can use "ring a bell", as in "that does ring a bell", though that phrase usually refers to ideas or discussions, rather than visuals. Does that help?

Comment: I can't see any reason to suppose that *to ring a bell* is particularly associated with (abstract?) "ideas or discussions". To me at least, there's nothing unusual about usages such as *That painting rings a bell. Didn't you have it on the bedroom wall when we were roommates at college together?*

Comment: Valid point; I've only ever used it in the context of a thought or idea, never a physical object (such as in this example).

Answer (score 1):

With a slight rewording the police chief could ask

> Do you **recognize** this painting?

As given by the [Oxford Dictionaries](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/recognize)

> **recognize**
>   (*British* recognise)
>   VERB
>
> **1** Identify (someone or something) from having encountered them before; know again.